# Skip the load of Child Init method from parent during onload in aura component Salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a below lightning component:

```
<!--ParentCmp--->
<aura:component>

...

<aura:if isTrue="{!!v.condition}">
    <c:childCmp/>
</aura:if>

...

</aura:component>
```

When this above component gets loaded, the init method of child component `childCmp` gets called even if the condition `isTrue="{!!v.condition}"` is false.

I do not want to load the init of `childCmp` which is why I kept it in False condition but still the init method of child component `childCmp` is getting invoked, what should I do to stop the loading of childCmp Init when parent component loads?

Answer (score 0):

Set the condition such that the `ifTrue` property evaluates to `false` on initial rendering.

```
<aura:attribute name="condition" default="true" type="Boolean" />
```

...

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!!v.condition}">
```

Note that `{!!v.condition}` means "when condition is false", because you have an extra `!` in there. I made no assumption about if you meant to do this, just be aware that `!` in an expression is the not operator.

Also, just be aware that `"False"` is a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), while `false` (no quotes, lowercase) is a proper [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). Make sure you're not accidentally setting a truthy value.

Comment: I did set the value to false on the initial load but still the init of child is getting invoked.

Comment: @sfdc07 I tested this, and it did work as expected. There's something wrong with your code if the initializer is being called. Copy-paste [this code](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/941cc218a5f320bb7bd6e78a97f0d321) in to an org. Change false to true to see the initialization happen.